# Xsendfile File Not Found

Tags: php, file

I am using mod_xsendfile on Dreamhost to download large zip files (50mb+)

I have mod_xsendfile enabled, and "XSendFile on" in my .htaccess.

When I give the

```
header('X-Sendfile: "'.$fullPath.'"');
```

command, using the full path to a file that **does** exist on the server, I am getting a webpage not found error.

readfile() finds the file just fine and serves it, but the .zip files have gotten too large for php to handle.

Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it, so possibly this solution will work for you.

First thing to do is to check your Apache error logs (for me, located in /etc/httpd/logs). This is what I found in mine:

```
[Wed Sep 05 14:29:02 2012] [error] [client ?.?.?.?] (20023)The given path was above the root path: xsendfile: unable to find file: /path/to/file
```

The problem was, the file I was looking to serve was located above the DocumentRoot (for me, /var/www/html) as defined in httpd.conf.

My solution was to create a symlink in the DocumentRoot directory that pointed to the directory which contained the file I want to serve. I used the following command:

```
ln -s /path/to/file_dir /path/to/doc_root/file_dir
```

Then all I had to do was have PHP point xSendFile to the symlink:

```
header("X-SendFile: /path/to/doc_root/file_dir/file_name.ext");
```

Comment: This is a bit of a hack. Instead, you should set the XSendFilePath directive to the absolute path your working directory in your Apache confs. E.g. `XSendFilePath /Path/To/Your/Working/Directory/` - this will whitelist that directory and allow xsendfile to serve files from it.

Answer (score 6):

There is actually an apache/xsendfile configuration value for this.

In your host configuration, you can simply add:

```
XSendFilePath /tmp
```

Where `/tmp` is wherever you want xsendfile to be able to access. It's a whitelist, and I believe you can add more than one.

For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    XSendFile On
    XSendFilePath /tmp
</Directory>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. mod_xsendfile does some security checks to ensure that files should be allowed to be served from a given directory, and sometimes that doesn't work automatically. FYI, XSendFilePath can also take multiple paths, so you can whitelist multiple directories.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the easiest solution for this:

```
header('X-Sendfile: '.realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$the_rest_of_path);
```

This way it's working perfectly for me.

Comment: Note: This is because the X-Sendfile header requires absolute paths. Given the OPs $fullPath variable, we can safely assume that he's already using absolute paths.